# CakePHP 3.0 - $this->Model->get($id) thows MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to create a delete function inside a controller (PropertyController.php) which will delete a record from the DB and then fire an event.

However it's throwing this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'get' at line 1
```

Stack trace:

```
    CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 460 → PDOStatement->execute(array)
    CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 426 → DboSource->_execute(string, array)
    CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 668 → DboSource->execute(string, array, array)
    CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 611 → DboSource->fetchAll(string, array, array)
    CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 827 → DboSource->query(string, array, Property)
    APP/Controller/PropertyController.php line 367 → Model->__call(string, array)
    APP/Controller/PropertyController.php line 367 → Property->get(integer)
    [internal function] → PropertyController->delete(string)
    CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(PropertyController, array)
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
    CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PropertyController, CakeRequest)
    APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

I can access records through find() but for some reason not with get().

/property/delete/2000

Function in PropertyController.php:

```
public function delete($propertyAgentRef = null) {

    // Get property entity
    $property = $this->Property->get($propertyAgentRef);

    // Delete
    $result = $this->Property->delete($property);

}
```

Property.php (Model)

```
class Property extends AppModel {
   public $primaryKey = 'agent_ref';
   public $hasMany = array(
  'PropertyMediaImage' => array(
      'className' => 'PropertyMediaImage',
      'foreignKey' => 'agent_ref',
      'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true
  ),
  'PropertyMediaFloorPlan' => array(
      'className' => 'PropertyMediaFloorPlan',
      'foreignKey' => 'agent_ref',
      'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true        
  ),
  'PropertyMediaDocument' => array(
      'className' => 'PropertyMediaDocument',
      'foreignKey' => 'agent_ref',
      'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true        
  ),            
  'PropertyMediaVirtualTour' => array(
      'className' => 'PropertyMediaVirtualTour',
      'foreignKey' => 'agent_ref',
      'dependent' => true,
        'cascadeCallbacks' => true
  )
);
}
```

Do I need to add a get method into my Model controller? Or is it perhaps an issue with my custom primary key?

Comment: Why do you try `Your own coding conventions` ? Id is your primary key in your table ,correct ?

Comment: Instead of get method use `$this->Property->find('first',array('agent_ref'=>$propertyAgentRef);`

Comment: Thanks, I'm on track now.

Comment: Hi , what was the issue ?

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I was using the wrong function call, get() isn't present in my CakePHP version which is  2.6.1. I also just found that I don't need to even get the record as I can just pass the primary key to the Model->delete() function.

Comment: @eb_dev You don't need to get() it in Cake3 either, you can do `$this->Table->newEntity(['id' => $id])` and then call delete() with that entity, no need for another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows that you're using CakePHP 2.x but the way you try to use it is CakePHP 3. CakePHP 2.x doesn't feature entity objects. None existing model methods in Cake2 are executed as SQL, thats the cause of the error.

Double check which documentation you're reading, make sure you follow the 2.x documentation if you use Cake2.

When asking a question *always* name the exact CakePHP version you're using.

Comment: Ah I see! Now I feel foolish...thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious :)